# How to get each elements from char string in c?

Tags: c, string

I would like to put first 7 elements of buf[20] into char A to G. I expect the result could be `1 H, 2 e, 3 l, 4 l,5 o, 6 ,7 W`, but what I got is `1 H,2 e olWH,3 lWH,4 le olWH,5 olWH,6  olWH,7 WH`. Could anyone explain this, please?

```
#include <stdio.h>
     char buf[20]="Hello World";
     char A,B,C,D,E,F,G;
    int main()
    {

        A=buf[0];
        B=buf[1];
        C=buf[2];
        D=buf[3];
        E=buf[4];
        F=buf[5];
        G=buf[6];
        printf("1 %s,2 %s,3 %s,4 %s,5 %s,6 %s,7 %s",&A,&B,&C,&D,&E,&F,&G);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: A char is a byte in memory, that's all.  A string is a series of bytes terminated by a zero byte.  So, using %s on the address of your character prints the character, and whatever junk is in memory up until a null byte (or until a memory fault occurs and the program dumps core).  You want %c.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `%c` and `A`-`G` instead of `%s` and `&A`-`&G`.

`%s` is the printf format for strings, and `%c` is the printf format for characters.

A C string is the memory address of a sequence of characters that is terminated by the special character `'\0'`. `buf` is a string, but A through G are just one character each and their address can't be treated as a string.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You solved the problem which takes me 3 hours to think where things go wrong.